# Concatenate multiple cell arrays using for loop?

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation, cell-array

I have a cell array containing 750 "documents" (750 arrays of words within the single cell array). I am trying to concatenate all of the words to make a single array. 
So far I know I need to use a for loop to iterate through each array and append to the end of the last one, however my code is giving me the wrong answer:

```
list = cell(1,1);
    for i = 1:length(docs)
   prevList = list;
    list = [prevList;docs{i}];
end
```

My thoughts are that my initialisation of list is incorrect as it produces:

```
    [1x1635 char]
    [1x1476 char]
    [1x531  char]
    [1x103  char]
    [1x1725 char]
    [1x344  char]
    [1x463  char]
    [1x739  char]
    [1x762  char]
    [1x1139 char]
    [1x89   char]
    [1x361  char]
    [1x334  char]
    [1x520  char]
    [1x219  char]
and so forth...
```

as opposed to a list of words.

If anyone could help me, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: What does `doc{i}` contain exactly? Is it a char vector, or a cell array? Can you give a small example for two or three documents with a few words each?

Comment: By the way, `[1x1635 char]` is just Matlab's way of shortening a string inside a cell that is too long to print out to the command window. If the line was fewer that 80 characters (I believe -or whatever your preference is set to) then the actual string would be shown.

Comment: doc{i} is a cell array. There is a paragraph of words in each cell, doc{1}, doc{2} and so on. 
@horchler from what you said, maybe that means my code was correct from the beginning?

Comment: @Sadeep: To be clear, what is `class(doc{1})`? If my answer works then it should be `char`. You may be confusing the elements of a cell array (indexed with `{}` brackets) with the cells themselves.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the answer to your question, however you have been great help. I will search more tomorrow as it is late here, so appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `for` loop needed. Let's use a small example:

```
str1 = 'The quick brown ';
str2 = 'fox jumped over the ';
str3 = 'lazy dog. '
docs = {str1;str2;str3} % Your cell array containing arrays of text in each row

docs_cat = [docs{:}] % Concatenate
```

which returns:

```
docs_cat =

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

Comment: It might take a while for OP to do this 750 times!

Comment: @David: The OP indicated that the cell array (`docs` in this example) already existed. So all that is needed is the last line. The rest just provides an example.

Comment: This makes sense cheers. If I wanted to have unique words only appearing, using unique(), how would this work?

Comment: @Sandeep: You're welcome. Please accept / vote up answers that you find helpful. I'm not sure what you asking with regards to `unique`. It seems like a separate question not related to this one. Perhaps your should formulate a new question specifically about that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a quicker solution to append, but you should be able to do the following:

```
list = prevList;
prevLength = length(list);
for i=1:length(docs)
    list{prevLength+i} = docs{i}
end
```

It doesn't matter that 'prevLength+i' is out of range during assignment.

Comment: I'm not too sure how that would work as prevList isn't initialised? I have been asked to do it using the var = {x;y} format.